# Wikipedia small writing on surface pro

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro, wikipedia

When I use the English version of Wikipedia on my Surface Pro it apparently thinks I have a large screen resulting in the display of unreadably small writing.

I have two Surface Pros both with this problem.

What is causing this?

Comment: As a workaround, you can press the ctrl and + keys to magnify the display of the web page. (ctrl with - shrinks it.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is a touch-screen  so it is easy to magnify but then you have to keep shifting the display left/right to read each line. It is not impossible to read just very inconvenient.

Comment: Is this the website or an app?

Comment: @Nemo With ctrl++ it's the browser that does the magnification, so it stays within the browser's window and you won't need to shift it left/right.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. Worked perfectly. Do you want to write an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> keys to magnify the display of the web page. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> shrinks it.)

That causes the browser itself to magnify the page rather than the OS, so the page stays within the bounds of the browser's window and you don't need to shift the display left and right to view the entire width of the page.

As an alternative to using the keyboard, there is usually a "Zoom" option in the browser's menus. Another way is to hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and use the scroll wheel on the mouse to adjust the magnification.